# How to calculate stock value from flow data in r?

Tags: r, loops

My problem is to calculate capital stock (ks) data from gross fixed capital formation (gfcf) for a set of countries. The data frame (gfcf.asean) given below. I can do it for a single country using a for loop. I have tried to do it for the set of countries using a combination of repeat and for loop, but I end up with several columns for capital stock for each country. I want them to be in one column. How can I do this. Or is there any smarter way of doing this in r.

```
>  gfcf.asean
       year country.code         gfcf
282560 1991          IDN 5.833088e+10
283860 1991          MYS 2.126583e+10
285160 1991          PHL 1.278487e+10
286460 1991          SGP 1.600550e+10
287760 1991          THA 5.010578e+10
289060 1991          VNM 2.240149e+09
290360 1991          WLD 6.965000e+12
291660 1992          IDN 6.430775e+10
292960 1992          MYS 2.199244e+10
294260 1992          PHL 1.378632e+10
295560 1992          SGP 1.733154e+10
296860 1992          THA 5.272118e+10
298160 1992          VNM 3.231399e+09
299460 1992          WLD 6.857560e+12
300760 1993          IDN 6.416656e+10
302060 1993          MYS 2.700124e+10
303360 1993          PHL 1.487179e+10
304660 1993          SGP 2.031462e+10
305960 1993          THA 5.729194e+10
307260 1993          VNM 4.395673e+09
308560 1993          WLD 6.756500e+12
309860 1994          IDN 7.486763e+10
311160 1994          MYS 3.041869e+10
312460 1994          PHL 1.615879e+10
313760 1994          SGP 2.022949e+10
315060 1994          THA 6.340091e+10
316360 1994          VNM 6.175503e+09
317660 1994          WLD 7.088970e+12
318960 1995          IDN 8.464586e+10
320260 1995          MYS 3.826020e+10
321560 1995          PHL 1.672489e+10
322860 1995          SGP 2.312726e+10
324160 1995          THA 7.243849e+10
325460 1995          VNM 7.229940e+09
326760 1995          WLD 7.440790e+12
328060 1996          IDN 8.882578e+10
329360 1996          MYS 4.047176e+10
330660 1996          PHL 1.880814e+10
331960 1996          SGP 2.512164e+10
333260 1996          THA 7.620697e+10
334560 1996          VNM 8.258715e+09
335860 1996          WLD 7.742300e+12
337160 1997          IDN 9.443335e+10
338460 1997          MYS 4.501902e+10
339760 1997          PHL 2.100785e+10
341060 1997          SGP 3.002745e+10
342360 1997          THA 5.949791e+10
343660 1997          VNM 9.033046e+09
344960 1997          WLD 8.197920e+12
346260 1998          IDN 5.756923e+10
347560 1998          MYS 2.564089e+10
348860 1998          PHL 1.758853e+10
350160 1998          SGP 2.266491e+10
351460 1998          THA 2.922497e+10
352760 1998          VNM 1.017384e+10
354060 1998          WLD 8.346940e+12
355360 1999          IDN 4.419173e+10
356660 1999          MYS 2.465061e+10
357960 1999          PHL 1.529022e+10
359260 1999          SGP 2.521789e+10
360560 1999          THA 3.170122e+10
361860 1999          VNM 1.029590e+10
363160 1999          WLD 8.646940e+12
364460 2000          IDN 5.191233e+10
365760 2000          MYS 3.200257e+10
367060 2000          PHL 1.545788e+10
368360 2000          SGP 3.168858e+10
369660 2000          THA 3.528954e+10
370960 2000          VNM 1.133676e+10
372260 2000          WLD 9.175470e+12
373560 2001          IDN 5.635788e+10
374860 2001          MYS 2.902009e+10
376160 2001          PHL 1.916395e+10
377460 2001          SGP 2.510803e+10
378760 2001          THA 3.624767e+10
380060 2001          VNM 1.255752e+10
381360 2001          WLD 9.042610e+12
382660 2002          IDN 5.384425e+10
383960 2002          MYS 3.131511e+10
385260 2002          PHL 2.216559e+10
386560 2002          SGP 2.346879e+10
387860 2002          THA 3.841156e+10
389160 2002          VNM 1.415547e+10
390460 2002          WLD 9.052190e+12
391760 2003          IDN 5.968056e+10
393060 2003          MYS 3.084186e+10
394360 2003          PHL 2.206637e+10
395660 2003          SGP 1.638484e+10
396960 2003          THA 4.360131e+10
398260 2003          VNM 1.583461e+10
399560 2003          WLD 9.479530e+12
400860 2004          IDN 6.380063e+10
402160 2004          MYS 3.295775e+10
403460 2004          PHL 2.157304e+10
404760 2004          SGP 2.477270e+10
406060 2004          THA 4.916412e+10
407360 2004          VNM 1.750371e+10
408660 2004          WLD 1.019580e+13
409960 2005          IDN 7.169988e+10
411260 2005          MYS 3.214628e+10
412560 2005          PHL 2.221114e+10
413860 2005          SGP 2.467030e+10
415160 2005          THA 5.544907e+10
416460 2005          VNM 1.945549e+10
417760 2005          WLD 1.073360e+13
419060 2006          IDN 7.266321e+10
420360 2006          MYS 3.490379e+10
421660 2006          PHL 1.885228e+10
422960 2006          SGP 2.890274e+10
424260 2006          THA 5.347299e+10
425560 2006          VNM 2.175774e+10
426860 2006          WLD 1.140890e+13
428160 2007          IDN 7.406906e+10
429460 2007          MYS 3.806581e+10
430760 2007          PHL 1.876331e+10
432060 2007          SGP 3.376898e+10
433360 2007          THA 5.399994e+10
434660 2007          VNM 2.758849e+10
435960 2007          WLD 1.205040e+13
437260 2008          IDN 8.328311e+10
438560 2008          MYS 3.874205e+10
439860 2008          PHL 2.314623e+10
441160 2008          SGP 4.339922e+10
442460 2008          THA 5.836742e+10
443760 2008          VNM 2.932057e+10
445060 2008          WLD 1.203160e+13
446360 2009          IDN 8.530274e+10
447660 2009          MYS 3.509311e+10
448960 2009          PHL 2.113724e+10
450260 2009          SGP 3.430332e+10
451560 2009          THA 4.367635e+10
452860 2009          VNM 3.058498e+10
454160 2009          WLD 1.069680e+13
455460 2010          IDN 9.281220e+10
456760 2010          MYS 4.397135e+10
458060 2010          PHL 2.781962e+10
459360 2010          SGP 3.615494e+10
460660 2010          THA 5.621421e+10
461960 2010          VNM 3.376780e+10
463260 2010          WLD 1.170330e+13
464560 2011          IDN 1.025810e+11
465860 2011          MYS 4.499587e+10
467160 2011          PHL 2.836285e+10
468460 2011          SGP 4.075075e+10
469760 2011          THA 5.629597e+10
471060 2011          VNM 3.147057e+10
472360 2011          WLD 1.224180e+13
473660 2012          IDN 1.199180e+11
474960 2012          MYS 5.501693e+10
476260 2012          PHL 2.746088e+10
477560 2012          SGP 5.167503e+10
478860 2012          THA 6.573205e+10
480160 2012          VNM 3.220552e+10
481460 2012          WLD 1.266920e+13
> 

   Codes:

    #############   construct capital stock ##########

    # Note: Formula for calculating capital stock, 
    #  k(0) = gfcf.91/(g+d)  
    #  k(t+1) = k(t)-dk(t)+GFCF(t) 
    #  where g = avg growth of GFCF over 1991-2012
    #  here g is taken as the slope of the relevant lm()
    #  d = depreciation rate, 0.05

    # Capital stock for a single country (e.g. IDN)

    country <- subset(gfcf.asean, country.code=="IDN")
    country$ks <- NA
    g <- lm(log(gfcf)~year, data=country)$coef[2]
    d <- 0.06

    country$ks[1] <- country$gfcf[1]/(g+d)

    i <- 1
    for (i in 1:(length(country$gfcf)-1)){

    country$ks[i+1] <- country$ks[i] - d*country$ks[i] + country$gfcf[i]
    }

    head(country)

    #------------- capital stock for all countries -----------------

    gfcf.asean$ks <- NA
    country.set <- as.character(unique(gfcf.asean$country.code))

    i <- 1
    j <- 0
    repeat {
      j <- j+1

      country <- subset(gfcf.asean, country.code == country.set[j])
      g <- lm(log(gfcf)~year, data = country)$coef[2]
      d <- 0.06

      country$ks[1] <- country$gfcf[1]/(g+d)

      for (i in 1:(length(country$gfcf)-1)){

    country$ks[i+1] <- country$ks[i] - d*country$ks[i] + country$gfcf[i]

    }

          gfcf.asean <- merge(gfcf.asean, country[,c("year", "country.code", "ks")], 
                by = c("year", "country.code"), all = T)
          if (j > 6) break()
    }

    head(gfcf.asean, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done pretty easily without using loops....

```
# Make gfcf into a data.table
require(data.table)
gfcf.asean = as.data.table(gfcf.asean)

# State depreciation rate
d = 0.06

# Create a variable for year order
gfcf.asean[, yr.order := 1:.N, by = country.code]

# Create the first ks index by country code
gfcf.asean[, ks := gfcf / (lm(log(gfcf)~year)$coef[2] + d), by = country.code]

# Derive following calcs from ks index by country code
gfcf.asean[yr.order != 1L, ks := ks[yr.order - 1L] * 
             (1L - d) + gfcf[yr.order - 1L], by = country.code]
```

Comment: I have not much dexterity with data.table. I think that these codes are first calculating ks for all country .code and years based on the initial ks formula. Then replacing all these ks values, except for the first year of each country.code , with the second formula for ks.  Anyway, thanks for the answer.  I am accepting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use subset? Something like:

```
for(c in unique(gfcf.asean$country.code) ){
    temp = subset(gfcf.asean, country.code==c)
    ##Do calculations on temp for ks
}
```

Does that work for you?